# How to write Horner's Algorithm in Mathematica?

Tags: polynomials, algorithm

The pseudocode we were given is:

[image]

Right now I have:

```
p[x_] := 6 (x + 3) + 9 (x + 3)^5 - 5 (x + 3)^8 - (x + 3)^11

For[k = 0, n - 1, k++, For[j = n - 1, k, n++, p[x]]]
```

Comment: This is a question for an instructor, not a forum (so voting to close). Some hints: (i) The input is expected as an array of coefficients (ii) That will require and extracting its coefficients e.g. by expanding it.

Comment: `HornerForm[p[x]]/.x->r` ;)

Comment: Seriously, `CoefficientList` and `Do` might be of help here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `(Fold[x #1 + #2 &, 0, 
   ToExpression[
    CharacterRange["a", 
     FromCharacterCode[
      ToCharacterCode["a"] + 
       Exponent[11 x^3 - 4 x^2 + 7 x + 2, x]]]]]) /. 
 First[SolveAlways[
   11 x^3 - 4 x^2 + 7 x + 
     2 == (Fold[x #1 + #2 &, 0, 
      ToExpression[
       CharacterRange["a", 
        FromCharacterCode[
         ToCharacterCode["a"] + 
          Exponent[11 x^3 - 4 x^2 + 7 x + 2, x]]]]]), x]]`

Comment: `(Fold[x #1 + #2 &, 0, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]) // Expand
Fold[x #1 + #2 &, 0, 
 Reverse@CoefficientList[11 x^3 - 4 x^2 + 7 x + 2, x]]`